# systemctl throws error

Tags: systemctl

I just started to learn about systemctl, I tried to create a service file that will run a nodejs script but it fails to run and the error doesn't really tell me why.

Here are the steps I've taken:

1) Navigated to `/lib/systemd/system` and created a file using the following command:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/hello_env.service
```

2) Created the following service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/dev/index.js
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi.user.target
```

3) typed `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

4) Started the process:

```
sudo systemctl start hello_env
```

5) Checked status:

```
sudo systemctl status hello_env
```

And got the following error:

```
> hello_env.service   Loaded: loaded
> (/lib/systemd/system/hello_env.service; disabled; vendor pres   
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-01-29 16:00:37 IST;
> 2s ago   Process: 25605 ExecStart=/usr/bin/node
> /home/dev/index.j  Main PID: 25605 (code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE)
> 
> Jan 29 16:00:37 sf-env systemd[1]: hello_env.service: Main process
> exited, code Jan 29 16:00:37 sf-env systemd[1]: hello_env.service:
> Failed with result 'exit- Jan 29 16:00:37 sf-env systemd[1]:
> hello_env.service: Service hold-off time ove Jan 29 16:00:37 sf-env
> systemd[1]: hello_env.service: Scheduled restart job, re Jan 29
> 16:00:37 sf-env systemd[1]: Stopped index.js - starting the bot. Jan
> 29 16:00:37 sf-env systemd[1]: hello_env.service: Start request
> repeated to Jan 29 16:00:37 sf-env systemd[1]: hello_env.service:
> Failed with result 'exit- Jan 29 16:00:37 sf-env systemd[1]: Failed to
> start index.js.
```

Please note that If I navigate to `/home/dev/index.js` and run the script with `node index.js` it works just fine - please advise what I'm missing

Comment: Try to replace `type=simple` with `type=forking`.

Comment: doesn't work, getting error "Job for hello_env.service failed because the control process exited with error code"

Comment: Did you run `systemctl daemon-reload` afterwards? Does your script exit with a 0 if it works?

Comment: Yes I have, it didn't let me run systemctl start without it

Comment: As is so often the case, the log output that tells you what is going on is the part that comes before "Main process exited", that you haven't looked at or put into the question for other people to look at.  And you've truncated the log lines that you did retrieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it by echoing this line `ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/dev/index.js`, I then saw there was an error in the script.

So for future reference, debug the ExecStart to see that it actually works.